# Change price parameter based on form input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails form where a user can choose to purchase a product hourly or daily. I'm using a shopping cart to track each item purchased. The cart is passed line item objects when the form is submitted. I need to change the price of the item and change to to cost calculation based on whether the user chooses hourly or daily for their purchase. I'm not how I should test for the parameter and if I should do this in the model or controller of the item.

My Code is below. Thanks for the help!

**Form that is filled out**

```
<%= form_for LineItem.new do |f| %>
        <p><%= render :partial => "price" %> / 
            <%= f.select :day_or_hour, [['day', 'day'], ['hour', 'hour']], :id => 'day_or_hour' %>
    <div class="gearside_date_main">
        <h3 style="font-family: 'RockSaltRegular', 'JosefinSansStdLight', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;color: #71a41e; font-size: 16px; margin: 15px 0 5px 15px;">Rental Date</h3>      
            <%= f.text_field :rentstart, id: 'rentstart', :value => "Pickup"  %>
            <%= f.text_field :rentend, id: 'rentend', :value => "Drop Off"  %>
            <%= image_tag('calendar.png', :style => "float:left; padding-top: 8px") %>
            <%= f.hidden_field :gear_id, :value => @gear.id %>
            </br></br>
            <div class="gear_time_schedule hourlyshowhide">
            <span class="gear_time_schedule_container">
                <%= f.label :starthour, 'Pick Up Time', class: 'labeltext' %>
                <%= f.text_field :starthour, id: 'starthour',  :value => '' %>
            </span>
            <span class="gear_time_schedule_container">
                <%= f.label :endhour, 'Drop Off Time', class: 'labeltext' %>
                <%= f.text_field :endhour, id: 'endhour', :value => '' %>
            </span>
        </div>
            <%= f.submit "", id: 'rent_it' %>
        <% end %>
```

**Gear Model**

```
class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items

  def hourly_price
    price/24
  end
end
```

**Line Item Model**

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :gear

  def total_price
    gear.price * quantity
  end

  def set_rentprice price
   self.rentprice = price
  end

end
```

**Parameters in Line Item Database**

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gear_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cart_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `rentstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rentend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `rentprice` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `starthour` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `endhour` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_or_hour` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
```

**Create Action in LineItem Controller**

```
 def create
    @cart = current_cart
    case params[:day_or_hour]
     when 'day'
      price = Gear.weekly_price
     when 'hour'
      price = Gear.hourly_price # these methods have to be converted to class methods
    end
    gear = Gear.find(params[:line_item][:gear_id])
lineitem = LineItem.new(params[:line_item])
lineitem.set_rentprice price
@line_item = @cart.add_gear(lineitem, gear.id)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @line_item.save
            format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart }
            format.json { render json: @line_item, status: :created, location: @line_item }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @line_item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

**Cart Model**

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_gear(lineitem, gear_id)
    current_item = line_items.find_by_gear_id(gear_id)
    if current_item
      current_item.quantity += 1
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(lineitem)
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest a re-factor.

This looks like a good candidate for a many-many association.
Install the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem. For more info on nested forms, check [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=nested+form)

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :line_items
 has_many :gears, through: line_items

 attr_accessible :line_items_attributes

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items

 def total_price
  gears.sum(:price)
 end
end

class Gear < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :line_items
 has_many :carts, through: line_items
end

class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :cart
 belongs_to :gear

 attr_accessible :cart_id, :gear_id
end
```

Now, in your carts controller

```
def new
 @cart = Cart.new
end
```

I use [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) for cleaner views. You should consider using it.

**Nested_form will take care of adding & removing items through jquery :)**

```
<%= simple_nested_form_for @cart do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :line_items do |item| %>
   <%= item.input :rentstart %>
   <%= item.input :rentend %>

   #Select your gear like this
   <%= item.association :gear, as: :collection, label_method: :gear.nameorwhatever, value_method: :gear.id %>

   #Remove items using this link
   <%= item.link_to_remove "Remove this task" %>
  <% end %>

  #Add new item
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add an item", :tasks %></p>
<% end %>
```

Your cart controller's create action would be standard. accepts_nested_attributes for would update you lineItems magically.

Comment: Rahul, I'm not sure I completely understood where you suggest these go, so I've updated with my best guess. I've modified a little since I already had a field in the line item named "rentprice" where I was passing the price parameter. Now I get an error undefined method `set_rentprice'

Comment: lineitem needs to be an instance of the LineItem model. If you're creating the instance using params[:line_item], then maybe try something like this. lineitem = LineItem.new(params[:line_item]). followed by lineitem.set_rentprice price

Comment: Btw, since you're saving lineItem in a cart, please show me that model as well. Also, since you don't seem to be persisting anything in Lineitem, i don't think it needs to inherit from ActiveRecord. Maybe once you paste your cart model, i'll change my answer. Pardon my first attempt. Didn't have the patience to read all your code.

Comment: I updated my code. I got undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<LineItem:0x007ff9cbb6b7b0>

Comment: What does weekly_price & hourly_price actually mean? Also, could you create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) & copy your entire error there?

Comment: Major refactor suggested. This will work like a charm. Will include weekly & hourly logic after you explain it to me :)